# Check if circle is within polygon/rectangle/circle in leaflet and turfjs

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw, turf

I am using leaflet and turfjs. I am able to check whether rectangle/polygon/point is within another polygon. 
But I am not able to check the same for circle. I want to restrict user to draw circle inside other shape (polygon/circle/shape) etc.

Could anybody please help me to know how to do this?

This is how I check whether new shape is within polygon or not. It is working fine when new shape is rectangle or polygon. But for circle, it throws errors at  for "layer.getLatLngs()".

```
// create parent feature
var parentContainerBoundary = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [parentCoordinates]
            }
        }
    ]
};


        var pointWithinContainer = turf.within(newShapePoints, parentContainerBoundary);
        return pointWithinContainer.features.length != newShapePoints.features.length;
```

Comment: How exactly are you "not able to check"? Do you receive an error? An example with some code would help a lot here.

Comment: How is your circle different from a polygon?

Comment: @ericbrelsford, please check updated code.

Logic here is to get list of corner points of new shape and pass these new points to turf.within function second argument as Parent shape. 

For circle, it's not working. 

Could you please let me know is there any way to check if circle is within polygon or rectangle?

Thanks!

Comment: [The `L.Circle` class](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle) does not have a `.getLatLngs` method, which is probably the source of the error. It is a bit hard to say exactly, since you haven't included the code that creates your `newShapePoints` object. Because L.Circle does not have any easy way to access the points of the circle (the built-in methods only give you the circle's center point), you may need to create a proxy object that actually produces a polygon ([leaflet-geodesy](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-geodesy) is a good option here) and use turf.within on that.

Comment: @Balram It would be really helpful to see the full code for the situation that does not work (use jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com). As it stands now we have to guess at how `parentCoordinates` and `newShapePoints` are defined.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, [`L.Circle`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle) does not have a `getLatLngs` method (hence your error). It does have a [`getLatLng`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#circle-getlatlng) method (note, no **s**). The latter returns the centre of the point. You need to use a polygon that approximates a circle, in order to have access to `getLatLngs` (i.e. the vertices of the approximate circle).

The treatment of circles as polygons with a dense array of vertices is quite common in GIS, because it's a lot easier to work with than a true circle.